# save the last value in JSON through lambda nodejs

Tags: node.js, json, aws-lambda

I'm new to Lambda and I need to read data from an API for each 5 mins. but during each call, API is sending me whole bunch of data. I need to read only the new data which are available in the data set.

my question is, how can we maintain the last read record of the unique ID in AWS lambda? in my case I need to save the value of  **"Id": "ce4b69cb-9d31-11ec-8d58-005056b636f5"** into a variable or into a file in within the lambda.

```json
[
    {
        "Id": "1c43fbf1-33e2-11ec-8d56-005056b636f5",
        "Name": "America",
        "ThirdPartyId": null,
        "ImoNumber": null,
        "Classification": "Bulk Carrier",
        "YearBuilt": 2012,
        "LengthOverall": 180.000000000,
        "GrossRegisteredTonnage": 0.000000000,
        "NumberOfHolds": 4,
        "GearType": "Centre"
    },
    {
        "Id": "994c6be8-9aed-11ec-8d58-005056b636f5",
        "Name": "Australia",
        "ThirdPartyId": null,
        "ImoNumber": "9615157",
        "Classification": "Bulk Carrier",
        "YearBuilt": 2010,
        "LengthOverall": 199.980000000,
        "GrossRegisteredTonnage": 34832.000000000,
        "NumberOfHolds": 5,
        "GearType": "Centre"
    },
    {
        "Id": "ce4b69cb-9d31-11ec-8d58-005056b636f5",//This Id
        "Name": "Qatar",
        "ThirdPartyId": null,
        "ImoNumber": "9744051",
        "Classification": "Bulk Carrier",
        "YearBuilt": 2015,
        "LengthOverall": 199.870000000,
        "GrossRegisteredTonnage": 36321.000000000,
        "NumberOfHolds": 5,
        "GearType": "Centre"
    }
]
```

couldn't do anything.

Comment: What have you tried? What happened? Do you understand how lambda works?

Answer (score 0):

1. Storing the last ID read by your Lambda in the memory or in the ephemeral file system is not a reliable solution because there is no guarantee that we'll get the same runtime environment on all the subsequent invocations of the Lambda function.
2. You may want to consider using a reliable storage to persists the last read ID. You may want to consider `DynamoDB` as it offers a cost efficient storage that fits your requirements.

Here is an [article](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-runtime-environment.html) that explains more about Lambda execution environments.